# Wireless connection issue

Tags: wireless

I just installed Xubuntu alongside Windows 8.1 on my Acer laptop and I can't connect to the internet.There's no problem to connect from flash drive live session and there was no problem during installation. Broadcom linux driver is not loading when I click on it. It picks "do not use this device" option right away. I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Broadcom uses bcmwl-kernel-source. Those packages and its dependency dkms are on the installation DVD or USB. Insert the install media and go to **pool > restricted > b > bcmwl** and **pool > main > d > dkms** drag and drop the bcmwl deb package to some folder on your PC (eg: to your desktop) (Otherwise directly install from the USB or DVD itself). . Now we install the deb files. Open a terminal and:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo modprobe wl
```

I think it'll solve your issue with wifi connectivity.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for a quick reply. I dragged and dropped bcmwl and dkms folders to Xubuntu desktop and I copied and pasted the above command but terminal is asking me for a password. Sorry for the silly question but what's the password? Terminal doesn't allow me to write antyhing.

Comment: that is you user account password. in-order to carry administrative tasks you should have the privilege, for that purpose we are using 'sudo'. you can get one entire session as administrator/root power by issuing sudo -i.

Comment: Do I have to be connected to the internet via ethernet to install the packages from bcmwl folder?

Comment: no, nothing to do with internet, you already have .deb installation file with you, so you have to install it using dpkg (debian package manager) thats all. just copy the files, that i've already told (  pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and pool > main > d > dkms) from your bootable usb drive or from a bootable DVD/CD and install it.

Comment: Folders bcmwl and dkms contain only something like bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu 0.1_amd64.deb. When I click on it I'm being redirected to Ubuntu software centre where I can install drivers. Afcourse I can't do that because I have no connection. When I'm coping and pasting 3 lines in terminal (all at the same time) and I'm writing password that I can't see :) I'm receiving errors( eg.error processing archive*.deb (--install): cannot access archive: no such file or directory.Errors were encountered while processing: *.deb) Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: While typing your password on command line of-course you won't be able to see the password, just type it without error and enter it., ok do this, first copy those files ( bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu 0.1_amd64.deb and the one in in the other folder ) to your desktop, then copy and paste the following on your command line.
cd ~/Desktop && sudo dpkg -i *.deb && modprobe wl

Comment: I decided to connect my laptop to the internet at work via ethernet. I did system updates and wireless is now working. I don't know what was the problem.Thank you for your help and time and sorry for being such a pain. I'm new to Linux but I'm a quick learner. Thanks again :)